# Find minimum value in an array that is larger than another column in R

Tags: r, rowwise

I need to find the minimum values of three columns that are bigger than the values in another column. Say these five individuals entered a hospital in different months of the year, and they suffered several heart attacks before and after hospitalization. I need the first heart attack after hospitalization.

```
id<-c(100,105,108,200,205)
hosp<-c(3,5,2,6,2)
attack1<-c(1,6,3,4,1)
attack2<-c(4,7,9,10,NA)
attack3<-c(5,10,NA,NA,NA)
out<-c(7,12,11,12,9)

data <- data.frame(id,hosp,attack1,attack2,attack3,out)

   id hosp attack1 attack2 attack3 out
1 100    3       1       4       5   7
2 105    5       6       7      10  12
3 108    2       3       9      NA  11
4 200    6       4      10      NA  12
5 205    2       1      NA      NA   9
```

So the data should end up looking something like

```
   id hosp attack1 attack2 attack3 out afterh
1 100    3       1       4       5   7      4
2 105    5       6       7      10  12      6
3 108    2       3       9      NA  11      3
4 200    6       4      10      NA  12     10
5 205    2       1      NA      NA   9     NA
```

This is my attempt which did not work:

```
min_f<-function(a){
  x<-min(a[a>hosp])
}

data %>% mutate_if(vars(attack1,attack2,attack3),min_f())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following solution.

- Here c(...) refers to all variables in each row of your data set and I chose only those that starts with `attack`
- Then I chose only those values that are greater than the corresponding value of `hosp` in each row and since you were looking for the first one that is greater than the value of `hosp` I used `first` function to extract that
- `..2` also refers to the value of the second variable `hosp` in each row

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data %>%
  mutate(afterh = pmap_dbl(., ~ {x <- c(...)[3:5]; 
  first(sort(x[x > ..2]))}))

   id hosp attack1 attack2 attack3 out afterh
1 100    3       1       4       5   7      4
2 105    5       6       7      10  12      6
3 108    2       3       9      NA  11      3
4 200    6       4      10      NA  12     10
5 205    2       1      NA      NA   9     NA
```

As an alternative as mentioned by dear Mr. @Greg in a very large data set, we can use `min` function in place of `first(sort))` combination to ensure a faster evaluation time of the following solution. In case there is no value greater than `hosp` like in the last row `min` function would return `Inf` so I made sure that it would return the value `0` instead you can change it with the value you prefer:

```
data %>%
  mutate(afterh = pmap_dbl(., ~ {x <- c(...)[3:5];
  out <- min(x[x > ..2], na.rm = TRUE);
  if(!is.finite(out)) 0 else out}))

   id hosp attack1 attack2 attack3 out afterh
1 100    3       1       4       5   7      4
2 105    5       6       7      10  12      6
3 108    2       3       9      NA  11      3
4 200    6       4      10      NA  12     10
5 205    2       1      NA      NA   9      0
```

Comment: Do note that if the columns are out of order (`attack3` | `attack1` | `attack2`), we cannot rely on `first()` to find the _smallest_ value greater than `hosp`.

Comment: Thank you very much dear @Greg, you have pointed to a very subtle point. I made a slight modification.

Comment: My pleasure!  Though I do wonder if `first` ∘ `sort` would be as computationally efficient — on a lot of columns — as `min` (with something to ensure `NA` instead of `Inf` for an empty vector)

Comment: I made a slight modifications to my code. It was also a very good point, Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 2):

```
data %>% 
  # Nest attack columns
  nest(attacks = starts_with('attack')) %>% 
  # Only one row at a time
  rowwise() %>% 
  # Find first instance for each row
  mutate(afterh = first(attacks[attacks > hosp])) %>% 
  # Unnest attacks
  unnest(attacks)
```

Comment: +1 Cleanest and most extensible solution so far. The nesting of all `attack*` columns was a prudent touch. **Do note** that if the columns are out of order, however, we cannot rely on `first()` to find the smallest value greater than `hosp`.

Comment: good point. Didn't consider it in my quick-and-dirty solution.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it "dirty", per se. It keeps things pretty clean by leveraging `dplyr`, and it catches any and all `attack*` columns.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly similar answer but using `dplyr` only

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

data %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(afterh = {xx <- select(cur_data(), starts_with('attack')); first(xx[xx > hosp])})

#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      id  hosp attack1 attack2 attack3   out afterh
#>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1   100     3       1       4       5     7      4
#> 2   105     5       6       7      10    12      6
#> 3   108     2       3       9      NA    11      3
#> 4   200     6       4      10      NA    12     10
#> 5   205     2       1      NA      NA     9     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>